# Electron window.opener full support as in Browser

Tags: node.js, shared-memory, electron

I am working on a multi-windows desktop Electron based application and I need to share a object instances from the main application process with the other windows of the application. Currently in browser (Chrome 52.0.2743.116) you can reference window.opener to achieve this. In browser window.opener (in child window) will give you the instance of the Window object from which window.opent(myURL) was called.

*For example if you set in `window.myData = {}; (Main window)` same instance of `myData` will be available in the (Child Window) and will be accessed via (`window.opener.myData`)*.

In Electron when I open window via `(window.opent(myURL))` window.opener is replaced with BrowserWindowProxy (Electron API) which does not expose the same window (Window object instance) from which the `(window.open(myURL))` was called. Is there a way in Electron to access window.opener the same way it works in Browser?

Using remote.sharedObject (Electron API) is not an option since it only serialize/deserialize data and can be used for passing data from one window to others but does not give access to same object instances across windows.

Answer (score 2):

To correct window.opener, and work facebook(and others) logins

You need use `webPreferences.nativeWindowOpen=true`, and set same `webPreferences.affinity` for mainWindow, and opened windows(hook on `mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window')`)
https://gist.github.com/Gvozd/2cec0c8c510a707854e439fb15c561b0

Comment: Tnx man, what you write sounds reasonable :) will test it and give you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are right about the `remote` api. From the [doc](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/):

> Each object (including functions) returned by the remote module represents an object in the main process (we call it a remote object or remote function).

Try this:

```
'use strict'
let Electron = require('electron')
let mainWindow = null

class myObj {
  constructor(d) {
    console.log('constructor ' + d)
    this.d = d
  }

  get data() {
    console.log('get ' + this.d)
    return this.d
  }

  set data(d) {
    this.d = d
    console.log('set ' + this.d)
  }
}

global.someObj = new myObj(1)

Electron.app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new Electron.BrowserWindow()
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })
})
Electron.app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    Electron.app.quit()
  }
})
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      let obj = require('electron').remote.getGlobal('someObj')
      console.log(obj)
      console.log(obj.data)
      obj.data = 2
      console.log(obj.data)
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```